# Do not understand where column_id and 'direction' were declared in this dashtable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, plotly-dash

I am really confused on how to sort in dash table.

I am following the documentation on the plotly website and am applying it my own `df`, yet I don't fully understand how it works. I feel I am missing some basics such as what is `sort_by=[]`? How does this then get used in:

```
dff = df.sort_values(
    sort_by[0]['column_id'],
    ascending=sort_by[0]['direction'] == 'asc',
    inplace=False)
```

I don’t get where `'column_id'` comes from or `'direction'`.

`df` in the example below is my own `df`. Please see my comments below. I am really confused!

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder2007.csv')

df[' index'] = range(1, len(df) + 1) # Why do we add this?

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

PAGE_SIZE = 5

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table-paging-and-sorting',
    columns=[
        {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in sorted(df.columns)
    ],
    page_current=0,
    page_size=PAGE_SIZE,
    page_action='custom',

    sort_action='custom',
    sort_mode='single',
    sort_by=[]
)


@app.callback(
    Output('table-paging-and-sorting', 'data'),
    [Input('table-paging-and-sorting', "page_current"), # How do i know what to put in input??
     Input('table-paging-and-sorting', "page_size"),
     Input('table-paging-and-sorting', 'sort_by')])
def update_table(page_current, page_size, sort_by):
    if len(sort_by):
        dff = df.sort_values(
            sort_by[0]['column_id'],
            ascending=sort_by[0]['direction'] == 'asc',
            inplace=False
        )
    else:
        # No sort is applied
        dff = df

    return dff.iloc[
        page_current*page_size:(page_current+ 1)*page_size
    ].to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I'm unsure on what `sort_by[0][‘column_id’]` means, i.e. where did `column_id` come from?

If you want an example, take a look here: https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

> ...what is `sort_by=[]`?

This refers to the function definition

```
def update_table(page_current, page_size, sort_by):
    ...
```

which then refers to the callback declaration just above, which is

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table-paging-and-sorting', 'data'),
    [Input('table-paging-and-sorting', "page_current"), # How do i know what to put in input??
     Input('table-paging-and-sorting', "page_size"),
     Input('table-paging-and-sorting', 'sort_by')])
```

This callback is run anytime the input, say a slider, changes based on user input.

This allows things to be very dynamic, and in the words of the documentation itself:

> It's sort of like programming with Microsoft Excel: whenever an input cell changes, all of the cells that depend on that cell will get updated automatically. This is called "Reactive Programming".
>
> I'm unsure on what sort_by[0][‘column_id’] means, i.e. where did column_id come from?

This is from the function definition parameters in `update_table()`. And those names are, again, from the callback declaration just above.

I would suggest breaking apart this example and build it up step by step, understanding each of the components that make up this application. There are a lot of moving pieces in the example you've shown. I would also experiment with changing some of those parameters you've pointed out and see what happens to the output to better understand their role in the app.

Here is a page from the official documentation that has a nice similar example to what you appear to want https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/interactivity.

Here is a great tutorial on using Dash and plotly https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-complex-reporting-dashboard-using-dash-and-plotl-4f4257c18a7f.

Good luck!